# Python: finding ranges for a list of lists

Tags: python, list, range

This may sound a little convoluted but is useful for working with big data. I am trying to analyse an extremely long list of lists called **Y**

How do I create a second list for holding the **ranges of the lists** that are held within Y?

**I've WRONGLY tried using the *abs* function, which I should have known wouldn't work for lists.**

```
ranges = []
for stuff in Y:
ranges.append(abs(stuff))
```

*TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'*

I am a student of python 3 on a steep learning curve so I really appreciate any pointers. :)

**Edit:** For the sake of example here are 3 lists. The question is how to produce a list consisting of the ranges of these lists?:

```
Y = [[0.61,0.62, 0.66, 0.65,0.64][0.89, 0.75, 0.99][0.98, 0.65, 0.12]]
```

Comment: Please define `ranges of the lists` by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52156496/edit) to include a concrete example.

Comment: Your stuff variable is a list and not a number

Comment: Please provide your expected output

Comment: Yes, abs obviously wouldn't work, but what to use instead? (these are lists of numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by range you mean the largest number minus the smallest number, try this:

```
ranges = [max(stuff)-min(stuff) for stuff in Y]
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes that's right - I'm sorry for asking such a basic question. I forgot about the min & max shorthand,

Answer (score 1):

If by range you mean that given a list [1,10,4] it should output (1,10) with the meaning `all numbers are within 1 and 10` you could just take the `min` and the `max` of each list in the list of lists.

```
listoflists = [[1,4,5,2,22,1],[12,5,1],[6,20,1]]
ranges = [tuple([min(l),max(l)]) for l in listoflists]
#[(1, 22), (1, 12), (1, 20)]
```